# Slint Rust how to use the paste() function on LineEdit?

Tags: slint

How is the paste() function working with Slint in Rust in a ui.slint file  ?

Doku :
LineEdit
A widget used to enter a single line of text. See TextEdit for a widget able to handle several lines of text.

Properties
......
has-focus: (out bool): Set to true when the line edit currently has the focus

Functions
......
paste() Pastes the text content of the clipboard at the cursor position.

```
I tried :
    path_to_open :=  LineEdit {                     // path_to:open.text    
                    //horizontal-alignment: center;
                    font-size: 14px;
                    width: 350px;
                    height: 35px;
                    placeholder-text: "Enter Dir"; 

                    //paste() => { } ?????
                    // on_paste: |text| line_edit.set_text(text) ???        
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

As also outlined in https://github.com/slint-ui/slint/discussions/4910, this  can be done by calling the function from a callback:

```
import { Button, VerticalBox, LineEdit, HorizontalBox } from "std-widgets.slint";
export component Demo {
    VerticalBox {
        alignment: start;
        HorizontalBox {
            alignment: center;
            Button {
                text: "Copy";
                clicked => {l.copy()}
            }
            Button {
                text: "Paste";
                clicked => {l.paste()}
            }
        }
        l := LineEdit {
            text: "Hello";
        }
    }
}
```